# logging round-trip load times of requests

Tags: javascript, timer, intervals, roundtrip

I am using a testscript to measure the round-trip times of a test page.
I dont need the measured time to be accurate, I just want the trend to be stable so i can see the increase in load times under high(er) load.

For this I use 2 methods (in javascript) to measure the loadtime.

1:

```
var start_time = (new Date).getTime();
//load the resource
var end_time = (new Date).getTime() - start_time;
```

2:

```
var time_passed = 0;
var timer = setInterval("time_passed += 10;", 10);
//load the resource
clearInterval(timer);
```

I have read that the resolution of the first method is low in most browsers,
the only browser who gives a "good" result is chrome

the second method is very stable across browsers and gives a constant result.

The measured times are, as was to be expected, very irregular for the date difference, and very stable for the interval timer.
My problem however is that i removed the date difference timer because it was unusable, once i removed it the interval measurements became very unstable. The measured times peak under and above the trend.

Can anyone explain why the interval is unstable once the date difference is removed.

And/or maby how to improve on the timing.

Comment: Why does method 1 have a low resolution? It seems to be more precise.

Comment: @pimvdb The guy who created the jQuery library explains it in his blog :)
http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript to measure it's own execution speed is considered fairly inaccurate. Instead, I'd recommend using built-in profiler (in Safari and Chrome) which enables you to measure even every single function call and network profiler which gives you accurate request times.

Comment: i use this timing as a part of a load-test on an active website about 220k users per hour, to test the load on the new features. The users who request the load page (trhough a async iframe) are real users with real latencies etc. because of this i cannot use a profiler to test a one-time round trip time. And the only thing i want to measure is the increase (or lack thereof) in round-trip times as the load increasese during the day.